# .htaccess force www. redirect on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I need to force www. on a subdomain, e.g. sub.website.com to www.sub.website.com

I have tried a lot of codes e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev.website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dev.website.com/$1 [R=301,L], no success
```

Tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] no luck.
```

If you have an answer please reply. Thanks
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.website.\com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```